# Using a function to parameterize the length of port in SystemVerilog module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog and in VHDL as well, we can parameterize the length of ports on modules/entities. This means that the bit length of a port can be changed by using a parameter/generic. The required parameter/generic is specified when the module is instantiated.

Is it possible to take a parameter value and pass it to a function that will then return a value that is then used to do the actual parameterization? This could be done explicitly or implicitly.

```
// Explicit way
register #( .WIDTH(MyFunc(64)) ) D_rg
(
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    .wen(1'b1),
    .D(data_in),
    .Q()
);

// Implicit way - this shall call the MyFunc internally on WIDTH parameter
register #( .WIDTH(64) ) D_rg
(
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    .wen(1'b1),
    .D(data_in),
    .Q()
);
```

I believe that the explicit method should be possible, but I am not sure about the implicit method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `parameter` by calling a **constant** function.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 13.4.3 *Constant functions*.  There is a long list of restrictions for a function to be considered constant.

This is legal if `MyFunc` is a constant function:

```
register #( .WIDTH(MyFunc(64)) ) D_rg
```

Verilog can not call function `MyFunc` internally or implicitly with this code:

```
register #( .WIDTH(64) ) D_rg
```